# rails multiple create (JSON through POSTMAN)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, postman

I want to create an API, and I need to create multiple post, like this (but the list can reach an undefined number of items):

```
{"item":{"name":"Objeto 1","description":"Descripcion 1","price":100}},
{"item":{"name":"Objeto 2","description":"Descripcion 2","price":200}},
{"item":{"name":"Objeto 3","description":"Descripcion 3","price":300}},
{"item":{"name":"Objeto 4","description":"Descripcion 3","price":400}}
```

I have this controller:

```
class ItemController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /item
  # GET /item.json
  def index
    @item = Item.all

    render json: @items
  end

  # GET /items/1
  # GET /items/1.json
  def show
    render json: @item
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
      render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])

    if @item.update(item_params)
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item.destroy

    head :no_content
  end

  private

    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :price)
    end
end
```

My question is, how can I spend this list? Do I need to create a new method?
I'm sending the JSON array through POSTMAN

This is the model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Comment: can I see the Item model and related models?

Comment: Hi Leantraxxx, the model is the generated with scaffold, and this is the only model that I have

Comment: if you want  to save multiple posts at a time you need to loop in create action. and correct format to send multiple Data is:
{
"item":
{"name":"Objeto 1","description":"Descripcion 1","price":100},
{"name":"Objeto 2","description":"Descripcion 2","price":200},
{...........}
},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1

Without making changes to your `ItemsController`...

From Postman, you need to perform one request at a time, like this:
[image]

---

#### Option 2

If you want to send multiple items you need to modify your create action to accept many items or add a new one to handle this problem.
For example, you can create the `create_many` action:

In **/your-app/config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :items do
    collection do
      post 'create_many'
    end
  end
end
```

In **/your-app/app/controllers/items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  # other actions...

  def create_many
    # I've done a very basic implementation.
    # I think you can use a service to extract from the controller the ability to create multiple items and handle errors.
    # See "2. Extract Service Objects" http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)
    @items = []
    items_params[:items].each do |item_data|
      @items << Item.create(item_data)
    end
  end

  private

  def items_params
    params.permit(items: [:name, :description, :price])
  end
end
```

In **/your-app/app/views/items/create_many.html.erb**

```
<%= @items.inspect %>
```

From postman you can do:

[image]

---

#### Option 3

I asked you about your models because if you have a "user has_many :items" relation for example, you could create nested items in a Rails way using [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Tranks a lot for the quick answer. It was very helpfull and had no trouble with it